# Failure on local socket bind when wifi drops

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, sockets, routes, raspberry-pi

We are getting this strange issue on a raspberry pi.

We run a service on a socket that should work for both local and remote clients via wifi. 
The trouble is that stopping the remote network also stops connections from local clients.

Our python server sets up a socket like this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_DONTROUTE, 1)
s.settimeout(2)
s.bind(("", 8888))

while True:

    try:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
    except socket.timeout:
        print("Socket timeout on s.accept(), continuing")
        continue

    #do stuff
```

We have a local node client running a loop like this every second or so (and actually sending data):

```
// every second
socket.connect("localhost", "8888" );
socket.on('connect', function() { /* do stuff */ });
socket.on('error', function(ex) { });
```

Everything runs fine until we cut wifi. 
We server side times-out on s.accept and we see the error message in our logs.

I think that the socket is bound to listen on 0.0.0.0 but somehow does not fail over to 127.0.0.1 or some sort of strange routing situation occurs.

`netstat -an | grep 8888` gives

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          127.0.0.1:52794         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          127.0.0.1:52724         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          127.0.0.1:52740         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          127.0.0.1:52778         TIME_WAIT
```

`netstart -rn` gives

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    304    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 wlan0
```

I'm guessing that we just need a localhost route?

The local connections establish again when the wifi comes back up. So I don't there is some permanent dropping of the bind in the python socket.

the hosts line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` gives

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

We monitored ping to localhost during the test and it continues to function fine.
We also monitored netstat to see that port stays LISTENING on 0.0.0.0 Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: shot in the dark: have two server processes doing bind separately on localhost and wlan0 interface should help.

Comment: @bigdataolddriver can't do that, down stream shared resources would be a problem.

Comment: probably it is the attempt to lookup localhost in naming, try replacing it with 127.0.0.1 or just "" to use the any address..

Comment: @lossleader : early tests are showing that 127.0.0.1 in the client side is working. If you would like to post an answer on it, then we might be accepting it in about an hour or two. ... would be great to get some info on exactly why though. Is it that "localhost" was resolving to the 192 address? /etc/hosts says 127.0.0.1 localhost. Could node be using a different method?

Comment: what does your etc/nsswitch.conf look like?

Comment: @SpiRail if you are interested, i have  another shot about why, bind on ("",8888)  results binding on '0.0.0.0:8888', which means all available interface,  and any  later binding on 127.0.0.1:8888  would fail.  if the server setup 2 socket objects , one for '127.0.0.1:8888' , another for '192.x.x.x:8888',  it may act differently when wifi is cut off

Comment: @lossleader I added the hosts line from /etc/nsswitch.conf to the question now. We have run a few tests and the fix is looking good. The thing is, we have a bunch of other physical systems with the same configuration and we don't have the issues. So we are still looking for the root cause of what is different about this box.

Comment: @bigdataolddriver I read that binding on "" binds to all interfaces. We actually tried this with only '127.0.0.1:8888' on the server side and the issue still occurs. Also based on what lossleader is saying and our latest tests, its really looking like a client side issue

Comment: i compared the nsswitch.conf with my VM, and it is ```hosts:      files dns myhostname``` the interesting part is the ```myhostname``` missing, and according to a [online manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nss-myhostname.8.html)  it might be relevant .  is other physical systems with the same nsswitch.conf?

Comment: What error message do you see in the logs? What that `netstat` output from a time you were having the issue and the Wifi was cut and those four `TIME_WAIT` represent failed connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Easiest Solution

It looks like you should avoid any naming by using "127.0.0.1" as described in our comment discussion.

## In more detail:

According to the source and the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_options_connectlistener) (after [nodejs first tests for an ip](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8292b280ec9e6b8c2444cbe49350facc77f5fefa/lib/net.js#L992),) it checks if you've provided a lookup function as an option to connect, if not, it does its own ["dns.lookup"](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8292b280ec9e6b8c2444cbe49350facc77f5fefa/lib/net.js#L1010) call as the default. Despite the name, this function is actually trying to use system naming but might be subtly different, for example it may try to prefer ipv6.

To debug further you could try to make a more direct test case with dns.lookup and compare things like the output of `getent ahosts|ahostsv4|ahostsv6 localhost` against your different systems and when the wifi is down, as well as comparing other configuration like the gai.conf to try to determine if system naming is a bit different on this system or being given slightly different requests.